# How can I instantiate singleton class implemented in Bill Pugh method?

Tags: java

Hi Can please someone tell me the correct way how I can instantiate the below given singleton class?

```
    public class BillPughSingleton {

    private BillPughSingleton(){}

    private static class SingletonHelper{
        private static final BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
    }

    public static BillPughSingleton getInstance(){
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't the `Classloader` does the job for you.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking here. You have a perfectly fine implemented singleton pattern here (although the inner class `SingletonHelper` is not really needed). Can you further describe the problems you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
BillPughSingleton bill = BillPughSingleton.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite your class simply like this and no more need to `SingletonHelper` class

```
public class BillPughSingleton {

private static BillPughSingleton INSTANCE;
private BillPughSingleton(){}

public static BillPughSingleton getInstance(){
    if (INSTANCE==null) {
        INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

}

for instansiate you can try this:

```
BillPughSingleton instance = BillPughSingleton.getInstance();
```

you can find more another example [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples)